# Access tuple elemens in a nested list python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, tuples

I'm new to python, I have a list with a nested list and inside it contains tuples it looks like below

```
[('dad', 'mom', 'test1.txt')]
[('brother', 'sister', 'test2.txt')]
[('uncle', 'aunty', 'test3.txt')]
[('grandpa', 'grandma', 'test4.txt')]
```

I would like to access one list at a time, for example, I open test1.txt file from **1st list index[2]** and if the string **'dad' and 'mom'** are present then filter the file and read it likewise for text2.txt file if **'brother' and 'sister'** are there then read and filter.

I have below code:

```
for data in list:
    file= data[2]
    text_file= open(file,'r').readlines()
    if data[0], data[1] in text_file:
    #do something..
```

The above code is not giving me a proper output as per the requirement. Can kindly someone help me with this approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I have done it:

```
lis=[[('dad', 'mom', 'test1.txt')],
    [('brother', 'sister', 'test2.txt')],
    [('uncle', 'aunty', 'test3.txt')],
    [('grandpa', 'grandma', 'test4.txt')]]
for i in range(len(lis)):
    for j in lis[j]:
        f = open(i[2])
        lines = f.read()
        if i[0] in lines and i[1] in lines:
            #do sth
```

I have iterated the elements of the **list** in the **range** of the `length of the list: len(lis)`. This way `j` takes the values `0, 1, 2, 3`. Then I have used a `for loop` which iterates through the elements of the list. Hence, `j` assumes values of the elements of `lis` as `lis[0], lis[1], lis[2], lis[3]`.

Now that `j` has values of the list elements, we can use `i[(integer)]` and access the  elements of the elements of the list i.e, `"dad", "mom", "test1.txt"`, etc.

Hence we can apply conditions to `i[0] or i[1]` etc.

For example:

```
if i[0] == "dad":
    print(something)
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Is not clear what's wrong for you since you read the correct file name 4 times

I suppose you have to exit the for loop if you find what you are looking for with break statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use keywords like `list`

```
L=[[('dad', 'mom', 'test1.txt')],
[('brother', 'sister', 'test2.txt')],
[('uncle', 'aunty', 'test3.txt')],
[('grandpa', 'grandma', 'test4.txt')]]
for data in L:
  f=data[0][2]
  file1=open(f,"r")
  text_file=file1.read()
  if(data[0][0] and data[0][1] in text_file):
     #do something
```

Comment: If i use your method for example data[0][2] this gives a value '1' and says file not found. @Venkat

Comment: Hey sorry about that, I have edited can you please check now

Comment: sorry This also not working @Trilok , if you know can you guide me if its list of list means? i heard nested list is better than tuple list.

Comment: Can you please send me how your data looks like. What I have done is lists consisting of lists which contains tuple can you please let me know if thats not what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

```
lis=[[('dad', 'mom', 'test1.txt')],
    [('brother', 'sister', 'test2.txt')],
    [('uncle', 'aunty', 'test3.txt')],
    [('grandpa', 'grandma', 'test4.txt')]]
for i in lis:
    data=i[0][2]
    f=open(data,'r')
    file=f.read()
    if (i[0][0] and i[0][1])in file:
        pass
```